# Alternative to base64_encode

Tags: php

Are there any other encoding functions other than base64_encode for encoding text in PHP?

Edit: The purpose of the encoding functions:

To generate a string that can be used in a URL that can be used as an identifier.

For example, instead of http://www.something.com/?id=4&category=books&type=20

I would like to have:

http://www.something.com/?q=a3444aAbt3daj492klsj

So to get the variables one has to decode the only query string which is a hash.

Comment: Yes. Lots. Did you try the function search on the PHP website?

Comment: for one- or two-way encryption purposes?

Comment: @stillstanding: He did not mention encryption at all. On the other hand, he did not say anything about what he wants to do.

Comment: I have edited the opening post for clarity on the purpose why I need an alternative to base64_encode. Base64 encode is sometimes verbose and sometimes generates unusable characters.

Comment: still you have said nothing about what are you doing. What's wrong with id=4&category=books&type=20 and why do you need q=a3444aAbt3daj492klsj

Answer (score 3):

Yes, convert_uuencode for instance, but it might be a good idea to explain what you are trying to do!

Answer (score -1):

if you want the user not to see meaningful things written in address bar, i am just now on it.

1. in server you have to enable mod_rewrite (in apache)
2. create an .htaccess file in www root folder and put these on there. 1st 3 lines are for real dirs and files.

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico

   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [L]
3. create i.e. index.php and put something like these in it. you can use any kind of 2 way encryption you want. I am using clean url too.

   echo "<a href='".base64_encode("birinci/b/c")."'>link</a>

   echo "<a href='".base64_encode("ikinci/b/c")."'>link</a>

   echo "<a href='".base64_encode("ucuncu/b/c")."'>link</a>

   $var1 = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

   $var2 = base64_decode($var1);

   $arr = explode("/",$var2);

   $_GET["object"] = $arr[0];

   $_GET["action"] = $arr[1];

   $_GET["id"]     = $arr[2];

   if ($_GET["object"] == "birinci") {

   echo "a geldi!";

   } else if ($_GET["object"] == "ikinci") {

   echo "b geldi!";

   }